# soundmanager, autoplay, mute and loop

Tags: loops, playback, autoplay, mute, soundmanager2

I want to automatically play a sound when my site opens, I want it to loop endlessly and i want the user to be able to mute/play it it via a single mute/play button.

Here is mys script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

soundManager.setup({ 
url: 'scripts/soundmanager2/swf/',
flashVersion: 8,
onready: function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'mySound',
            url: 'audio/ambiance.mp3',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            stream:true,
            onfinish: function() {loopSound(mySound);},
            volume: 50
    });
    }   
$('#mute-play').click(function(){soundManager.togglemute('mySound');})
});             
</script>
```

The mute/play functionality works as I can start ans stop the sound manually but the sound doesn't start automatically when the site opens and the sound doesn't loop at all.

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try setting the option ´debug´ to true? Afterwards open the console in your browser, soundmanager will tell you whats going on ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `loopSound` function.

Try this:

```
function loopSound(sound) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    sound.play({
       onfinish:  function() {
         loopSound(sound);
       },
    });
  }, 1);  // window.setTimeout
}

soundManager.setup({
  url: '/plugins/soundmanager2/swf/',
  onready: function() {
    var sound = soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'music',
    url: 'audio.mp3'
  });
  loopSound(sound);
 }
});

$('#mute-play').click(function(){
  var sound = soundManager.getSoundById('music');
  sound.toggleMute();
})
```